# CTRL+D vs CTRL+C

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, output, input

Is it true to say that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> stops input execution while <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> stops output displaying (as plain data, without execution)?

Comment: If not a dupe, at least related: [What is the difference in using Ctrl+D and Ctrl+C to terminate cat command?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/379347)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not true.

However, it is true to say that <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> signals an End of Transmission (EOT) event which will generally cause a program reading input to close the input file descriptor.

<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is used for this because its place on the ASCII table corresponds to the analogous End of File control character, even though the actual EOF control character is not actually transmitted in this case.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> will generally (it's configurable with `stty`) generate an interrupt signal (SIGINT) which will be delivered to the processes that are in the current terminal (see `man kill`; `man 3 tcgetpgrp`).